# Error on OnClickListener Method

Tags: java, android

I am not sure why I am getting this error:  imgur.com/a/Hxz5O
Everything seems to be in the right methods and everything so it is a mystery to me why I am getting the error.
Here is my code:

```
package org.flinthill.finalprojectv2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.InputFilter;

public class mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button SuSe;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Button SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SuSe);
        SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        {
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){

                 }
            };
        }


    });

}
}
```

Comment: change from final Button SuSe  to SuSe

Comment: `new View.OnClickListener() {

        {
            new View.OnClickListener() {` <= pleae learn some java basics ... or if it was a typo ...then read your code carefully

Comment: sorry im new... Is that why I got 3 downvotes? lol whoops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `View.OnClickListener` inside another `View.OnClickListener` for no reason. Remove the second one e.g.

```
SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){

                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **setContentView()**  and your clickListener not correct.

```
 package org.flinthill.finalprojectv2;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
    import android.text.InputFilter;

    public class mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button SuSe;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.myView);
            SuSe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.MyButtonId);
            SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
```